# React Hooks - Changing state inside child does not reflect in parent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I have a parent component (App.jsx), Child component(Child.jsx) and a Hook (useHook hook un Hook.jsx file).

Hook.jsx below

```
import { useState, createContext } from "react";

export default function useHook() {
  const [one, setOne] = useState("First Option");
  const changeOne = value => {
    console.log("calling changeOne");
    console.log(value);
    setOne(value);
  };

  return {
    one,
    changeOne
  };
}
```

App.jsx below

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import "./style.css";
import useHook from "./Hooks";
import Child from "./Child";
export default function App() {
  const details = useHook();

  return (
    <div>
      <Child />
      Inside Parent Class: {details.one}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child.jsx below

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import useHook from "./Hooks";

export default function Child() {
  const details = useHook();
  return (
    <div>
      <form
        onChange={e => {
          details.changeOne(e.target.value);
        }}
      >
        <select id="inputState">
          <option value="First Option">First Option</option>
          <option value="Second Option">Second Option</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      Inside Child class: {details.one}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want the state 'one' which gets modified inside the Child component to be used in the parent component.
I imported the hook in parent component. But it looks like the both the components keep a separate copy of the state. The change I make inside the child component does not reflect in parent component. Why is it so? How I can use the state modified by the child component in the parent component.

[image: The output when first option is chosen in dropdown]

[image: The output when second option is chosen in dropdown]

Answer (score 4):

State is already lifted in the `App` component. However you're creating a new one in `Child` component.

Forward the `one` and `changeOne` to `Child` component as props.

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import "./style.css";
import useHook from "./Hooks";
import Child from "./Child";
export default function App() {
  const details = useHook();

  return (
    <div>
      <Child one={details.one} onChange={details.changeOne} />
      Inside Parent Class: {details.one}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then declare `Child` component props

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import "./style.css";

export default function Child(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <form
        onChange={e => {
          props.changeOne(e.target.value);
        }}
      >
        <select id="inputState">
          <option value="First Option">First Option</option>
          <option value="Second Option">Second Option</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      Inside Child class: {props.one}
    </div>
  );
}

Child.propTypes = {
   one: PropTypes.string.required,
   changeOne: PropTypes.func.required
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it now.